# How to get Rocket League players' MMR?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, rank

I would like to make sure to retrieve a player's MMR with the platform and the given id. I tried to see with the TRN Tracker API but they removed their API for Rocket League.

I wanted to scrape the site but nothing helps it necessarily asks me to "activate javascript" which I believe is not possible with python.
So I tried to scrape [another site](https://rlstats.net/) except that the site also asks for javascript and trying to display it with Insomnia (application to test and design APIs) it is protected by the Cloudflare anti DDOS system.

I would have liked to go through [rltracker pro](https://rltracker.pro/) but it is blocked in 2015.
Following all these failures, I wanted to fall back on the Rocket League API of Psyonix ... which is closed ...

So I continued my research and found this [site](http://api.yannismate.de/rank.html) which could really answer my problem but in fact I don't understand how he got access to the data while everything is closed and nothing is working.

Is there a place I've missed? I do not understand where to find this information at the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rlstats looks like it is scrapable to me see here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.now()

headers =   {
    'accept':'*/*',
    'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    }

url = 'https://rlstats.net/leaderboards/skills'

resp = requests.get(url,headers=headers)

print(resp)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser')

game_type_dict = {'10':'Duel','11':'Doubles','13':'Standard','12':'Solo Standard'}

final = []
for table in soup.find_all('table',{'data-platform':'Mixed'}):
    if table['data-skill'] not in game_type_dict:
        continue

    game_type = game_type_dict[table['data-skill']]
    for i,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr')):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        for k,td in enumerate(row.find_all('td')):

            if k == 0:
                rank = td.text.strip()
            if k == 1:
                name = td.text.strip()
                link = 'https://rlstats.net/'+td.find('a')['href']
            if k == 2:
                platform = td.text.strip()
            if k == 3:
                rating = td.text.strip()

                item = {
                    'game_type' : game_type,
                    'rank' : rank,
                    'name' : name,
                    'link' : link,
                    'platform' : platform,
                    'rating' : rating,
                    'scraped' : now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                }
                final.append(item)


df= pd.DataFrame(final)
df.to_csv('rocket_league.csv',index=False)

print('Saved to rocket_league.csv')
```